# Animate react navigation bottom tab navigation screen's components on load or when displayed in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, animation, react-navigation, react-native-animatable

I am searching to find a tutorial to implement lazy loading or showing some animation to the screen when bottom nav is routed to another screen(when screen changes) instead of displaying it without any animation. **I did not find page transaction animation.** but I managed to animate components in the screen when page opens, so that users see some animation when they open screen. [Lazy loading is only implemented on first time navigation loads](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#lazy).

I used [react-native-animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable) to animate component. I don't know if I am doing it in the correct way or not.

**Here is my code.**

```
constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
         
         dummyKey:4564654
            
        };
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', (e: any) => {   
       if(e){          
       
         this.setState({dummyKey:Math.random()})
       }
     })
}
render(){
 <Animatable.View key={this.state.dummyKey} animation={'bounceIn'} >
     //View to animate when loaded
    </Animatable.View>              
}
```

**I got these results**

[image]

**my Question**

1. Is this the correct way to do, what are the pros and cons?
2. How to achieve screen translation animation when screens are changed? ([I only see animation for stack nav screen change but not bottom tab nav](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animations))
3. If I add ref to Animatable.View component and if I try to call animation [like here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable#animations-1) on didcomponentmount animation is not getting triggered why(or can you please provide any example)?

**Also how to animate react navigation stack nav header when hiding and showing.**